# angular 2 how can keep correct type of form input when stringifying to JSON

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am building dynamic form as in [this](https://stackblitz.com/angular/yjplqlaqxejg).

I add another `TextboxQuestion` which expects a numeric input. On submit, when converting the form values to json as `JSON.stringify(this.form.value)` (as in `dynamic-form.component.ts` : onSubmit), the numeric value is being stringified as string.

I mean:

Instead of this (JSON):

```
{
  "mynumber" : 0
}
```

I got this:

```
{
  "mynumber" : "0"
}
```

To solve it, `onSubmit()` I have put control in a loop that checks every form element to convert its value to integer if its type is so.

Another solution was to create a ng model with appropriate types, but as the form is dynamic, I can not create interface/class for every possible form.

I bet that there is much simpler solution to keep correct types when using JSON.stringify.

Comment: The problem is not in any way related to `JSON.stringify`.

Comment: @AluanHaddad Who has told the contrary?

Comment: Trust me. The type is wrong in `this.form.value`. Try it out in your browser console, stringify an object with a property of type number. You will see that it's correctly serialized.

Comment: @AluanHaddad Yes I try to say the same thing :) There should be clever solution with angular 2 / typescript, which is what I am looking for.

Comment: In the link you provided, the dynamic form is generated using the `QuestionService` service. Are you using a similar approach? If so, how do you define your input? Is it of type `text` or `number`?

Comment: @Treeindev  I have copied the exact example. I have created NumberQuestion. The only difference from TextboxQuestion is its type of value is number instead of string.

Comment: @MertMertce then you should define a new `controlType` of type number. I am going to add a new answer for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that the form control type of your input is defined as string even if the input is of type number. To update this, make sure to define a new `controlType` for the number component.

As example, your `NumberQuestion` component should look similar to:

```
export class NumberQuestion extends QuestionBase<string> {
  controlType = 'number';
  type: number;
}
```

After defining the `controlType`, make sure to add a new option on the switch statement under the `dynamic-form-question.component.html` template:

```
<input *ngSwitchCase="'number'" [formControlName]="question.key"
        [id]="question.key" type="number">
```

Now the final output of your form should be similar to:

```
{"firstName":"Name","emailAddress":"Email","brave":"good","number":10}
```

Here is a [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-khvyum?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdynamic-form-question.component.html) to a working example.

Comment: Actually, I have also tried this, but I had another problem, let me ask you (Of course this answer answers actually the original question so I accept it. Thank you). I want to put default values when creating questions, when I put a 0, it is not shown (Other values are shown). What do I do is: questions= [.., new NumberQuestion({ ..., value: 0 }), ..]. If I do value: '0', then it is shown but again json problem. Do you have any idea? I'll try to fork your example to show you.

Comment: Here is: https://angular-khvyum-vjmznb.stackblitz.io

If you look EXAMPLE 1, the default value is shown, but in json it is a string. In EXAMPLE 2, the default value is 0 and is NOT shown. In Example 3, the default value is 9 and is shown and also json is correct. So, why 0 is not shown?

Comment: The `key` property should be different on each question. Otherwise the same value is assigned to each item. Also the value should be a number not a string. Finally, a default value of 0 will be displayed as empty input. New fork: https://angular-khvyum-dcykx6.stackblitz.io/

Comment: Sorry, I have forgotten to save my work. Look at this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-khvyum-vjmznb

What I try to do is not to show as empty input. Default 0, as 0, like other numbers.

Comment: You could define a placeholder instead of passing a '0' string. That way you ensure the input value is a number and the user sees a 0 in the input: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-khvyum-kik8rz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fquestion.service.ts

Comment: It won't save from having to fill 325347257 fields every time for the same.